# Visibility of var in for loop

Tags: java

I have a code snippet

```
public static StringBuilder stringYak(StringBuilder str) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 3; i++){
            if (str.substring(i, i+3).equals("yak")){
                result.append(str.substring(i + 3, str.length()));
                stringYak(result);
            } else {
                result.append(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Why I can't see the `i` variable in the second iteration i.e In DEBUG mode when I go in `stringYak()` then I just jump to `return result`
How should I use variables to reach them in recursion?

Comment: You need to add i as aparamter in stringYak().

Comment: I'd say you enter with the string `yak` and no iterations are made because of the loop conditions

Comment: I would recommend use system out before 'stringYak(result)'.